# How does Slash/A work? Installation & Setup?

Tags: c++, linux

Haiyo, everyone! I have a quick question, I came across this "language" called Slash/A [Found here!](https://github.com/arturadib/slash-a), I'm wondering if anyone knows any installation guides, or requirements (Linux, Windows, etc)?

I've tried a large variety of different things to try and get it to work! In the "SlashA.hpp" it has a #include for <unistd.h> and since that library is exclusive for Linux, so I've installed Kali-Linux, and that seems to have fixed that issue (w/o wiping my PC files lol).

However, even though it's working I keep getting this error when trying to run it (to test it; see if it's working):

```
    SlashA.cpp: In function 'bool SlashA::runByteCode(SlashA::InstructionSet&, SlashA::MemCore&, SlashA::ByteCode&, long int, long int, int)':
SlashA.cpp:335:10: error: 'SIGALRM' was not declared in this scope; did you mean 'SIGABRT'?
  335 |   signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
      |          ^~~~~~~
      |          SIGABRT
    SlashA.cpp:336:3: error: 'alarm' was not declared in this scope
  336 |   alarm(max_rtime);
      |   ^~~~~
```

This is the section it's talking about:

```
  if (!max_rtime)
    max_rtime = 3600*24*7; // that's a week's worth of runtime!

  core.C = &bc;
  core.c = 0;  
  iset.clear();

#ifndef DEBUG
  /* Setup the time-out handler */
  timedout=false;
  signal(SIGALRM, alarm_handler);
  alarm(max_rtime);
#endif
  
  iset.setMaxLoopDepth(max_loop_depth);
```

I'm really interested in using Slash (if possible), so any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: I've been testing it out a bunch more, and I've been getting this error now instead (after I issued the MAKE in the Slash/A dir):

```
g++ -c -O3 -Wall -I../lib main.cpp
g++ -L../lib main.o -o slash -lm -lslasha
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/9.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lslasha
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: Try including <unistd.h> and <signal.h>

Comment: Both of those have already been added, the error message is the same as the one above. :(

Comment: then your linux is broken because SIGALRM is defined in signal.h and alarm is defined in unistd.h